# Information won't show up in my console log

Tags: javascript, console.log

Code won't print in my console log. Why?
I am trying to print things from a dataset but it won't print for some reason.

```js
function totalPassengers(airportName) {
  var airport = getColumn("Busiest Airports", "Airport");
  var passengers = getColumn("Busiest Airports", "Total Passengers");
  for (var i = 0; i < airport.length; i++) {
    if (airport[i] == (airport[i] == airportName) ) {
return passengers[i];
    }
  }
}
console.log("The amount of passengers in this airport was: "+ getProperty("text_input1", "text") + totalPassengers());
function airport(airportName) {
  var airports = getColumn("Busiest Airports", "Airport Code");
  for (var i = 0; i < airports.length; i++) {
    if (airport[i] == airportName) {
      return (airports[i]);
    }
  }
}
console.log("The code of this airport is: " + airport);
```

Comment: "Uncaught ReferenceError: getProperty is not defined"

Comment: I have a text box to try and get the information for the name of the airport

Comment: `airport` is scoped to `totalPassengers()`, so it can be accessed outside of that function.

Comment: `airport` is a function in the scope of the `console.log` call. It's not clear what you're expecting. Please provide a [mre].

Comment: This is not a problem, because his function is called `airport`

Comment: Please read [ask], especially the section titled "Help others reproduce the problem".

Comment: I am hoping getColumn and  getProperty are defined but not shown in the snippet above. Can you paste that code also?

Comment: `function totalPassengers(airportName)` takes an argument `airportName` so why are you calling it by passing no argument as in ...`+ totalPassengers()`?  Also, your `function airport(airportName)` takes an argument `airportName` too, but you don't even call it, you just stringify the function: `"The code of this airport is: " + airport`.  I was expecting `airport(somethingHere)` and `totalPassengers(somethingHereToo)`.  Otherwise `airportName` will be `undefined` if you don't pass a value.

Answer (score 0):

Not quite enough data from the code right now, but we can probably assume that the `totalPassengers` function should return the number of passengers at a certain airport.

I advise you to pay attention to the if condition. Because the condition `if (airport[i] == (airport[i] == airportName))` is probably not correct, I think it should be something like `if (airport[i] === airportName)`.

It seems to me that the first function should be like this:

```js
function totalPassengers(airportName) {
  const airport = getColumn("Busiest Airports", "Airport");
  const passengers = getColumn("Busiest Airports", "Total Passengers");
  for (let i = 0; i < airport.length; i++) {
    if (airport[i] === airportName) {
       return passengers[i];
    }
  }
}

console.log(totalPassangers("NAME OF THE AIRPORT"));
```

As for the last line with `console.log`, you forgot to add the closing brackets and the argument.

```js
console.log("The code of this airport is: " + airport("NAME OF THE AIRPORT"));
```